# Word Pattern challenge in LeetCode

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge, hash-map

I solved [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-pattern/) problem from LeetCode:

> Given a pattern and a string str, find if str follows the same
>   pattern.
>
> Here follow means a full match, such that there is a bijection between
>   a letter in pattern and a non-empty word in str
>
> **Examples**:
>
> pattern = "abba", str = "dog cat cat dog" should return true.
>
> pattern = "abba", str = "dog cat cat fish" should return false.
>
> pattern = "aaaa", str = "dog cat cat dog" should return false.
>
> pattern = "abba", str = "dog dog dog dog" should return false.
>
> **Notes**:
>
> You may assume pattern contains only lowercase letters, and str
>   contains lowercase letters separated by a single space.

I was able to solve this problem by using a `Dictionary` to keep track of the relation between the `pattern` and the `str`:

```
public class Solution {
public bool WordPattern(string pattern, string str)
    {
        var result = str.Split(' ').ToList();
        var mapPattern = new Dictionary<char, string>();
        if (result.Count != pattern.Count())
        {
            return false;
        }
        string matchstr;
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var c in pattern)
        {
            if (mapPattern.TryGetValue(pattern[index], out matchstr))
            {
                if (matchstr != result[index])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if(mapPattern.ContainsValue(result[index]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                mapPattern.Add(c, result[index]);
            }
            ++index;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The approach I have currently looks up the `Dictionary` twice to see if it already exists as a `key` or as a `value` in the `Dictionary`, which I believe would be the reason for slowing this by a significant amount.

Can you determine if I can do away with looking up twice? This solution only runs better than around 36% of the other submissions for this current problem. So, I believe there must be a better and faster way.

Comment: 1) The .ToList() on the `Split()` can be removed. (Not sure how much it will save you). 2) Try resubmitting the same code a few times. I have received a large variation on the performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, this is a nice, clean solution, congratulations!

#### Performance

> Can you suggest If I can do away with looking up twice. Currently this solution only runs better that around 36% of the other submissions for this current problem. So, I believe there must be a better and faster way.

"Looking up twice" is not the appropriate term. You do one lookup by key, and another lookup by value. These are very different operations, and lumping them together as "two lookups" hides important details. Imagine a program that does one lookup in an array and one lookup with a Google search on the internet, and the author would wonder if slowness might be caused by doing "two lookups". It would hide a crucial detail that one of the "lookups" is clearly much slower than the other.

The lookup in the dictionary by key is very fast, an \$O(1)\$ operation.

The lookup by value in a typical dictionary (or hash map) implementation is much slower, \$O(n)\$, because dictionaries are *indexed* by key, not by value. They are designed for fast lookups by key, not by value.

To make the lookup by value faster, you can add a set for values.

#### Scope

It's good to limit the scope of variables to the minimum needed.

- `matchstr` should be declared inside the loop, as it is not needed outside
- `mapPattern` should be initialized after the early return, as it might not be needed

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My initial solution had two `Dictionary` like you had suggest but it execute a bit slower than this one. I'll try that one once again as well. Also leetcode run time can be unpredictable at times .

Answer (score 2):

Just a few small issues, the main thing (using a `HashSet` to keep track of the values) has already been covered.

---

```
var result = str.Split(' ').ToList();
```

You don't need this to be a `List` - it's fine as `string[]`.

`result` is a bad name. May I suggest `words` or `tokens`?

---

```
var mapPattern = new Dictionary<char, string>();
if (result.Count != pattern.Count())
```

You should check for the early return **before** creating your dictionary.
With `result` renamed to `words` and as an array, the `if` would be better as:

```
if (words.Length != pattern.Length)
```

---

```
string matchstr;
```

`word` or `token` would be a better choice depending on what you call the result of `string.Split()`.

---

```
if (mapPattern.TryGetValue(pattern[index], out matchstr))
{
    if (matchstr != result[index])
    {
```

You can combine these:

```
if (mapPattern.TryGetValue(pattern[index], out word) 
    && word != words[index])
{
    return false;
}
```

which saves you some indentation.

---

Overall, it's a good approach IMO. I submitted a similar approach with an extra hashset and first got a speed ~15% and then submitted it again and got a speed at ~85% so I think it's just pot luck.

---

Alternate solution using HashSet:

```
public bool WordPattern(string pattern, string str)
{
    var words = str.Split(' ');
    if (words.Length != pattern.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    var seenWords = new HashSet<string>();
    var letterToWordLookup = new Dictionary<char, string>();

    for (var i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
    {
        var letter = pattern[i];
        string word;
        if (!letterToWordLookup.TryGetValue(letter, out word))
        {
            word = words[i];
            if (!seenWords.Add(word))
            {
                return false;
            }
            letterToWordLookup[letter] = word;
            continue;
        }
        if (word != words[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Tested with:

```
var pattern = "aaabbbccc";
var test1 = "cat cat cat bat bat bat dog dog dog";
var test2 = "cat bat cat bat bat bat dog dog dog";
```

Approx twice as fast as [Paparazzi's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/148065/22816) solution on `test1`. Increases to more than 3 times faster on `test2`. YMMV.

Comment: @Paparazzi - did you check with the test cases I did? That's why I chose longer test cases because the ones given are so short constant terms are likely most important for perf.

Answer (score -1):

Not much but you could change index

```
foreach (int index = 0; index < pattern.Count; index++)
{
```

Use a HashSet to store current values

A related approach with no O(n) lookup

```
public static bool PatterMatch(string pattern, string match)
{
    Dictionary<char, int> dlPattern = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    Dictionary<string, int> dlMatch = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    List<int> lPattern = new List<int>();
    List<int> lMatch = new List<int>();
    int index = 0;
    int indexOut;
    foreach(char p in pattern.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (dlPattern.TryGetValue(p, out indexOut))
        {
            lPattern.Add(indexOut);
        }
        else
        {
            dlPattern.Add(p, index);
            lPattern.Add(index);
            index++;
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    foreach (string m in match.Split(' '))
    {
        if (dlMatch.TryGetValue(m, out indexOut))
        {
            lMatch.Add(indexOut);
        }
        else
        {
            dlMatch.Add(m, index);
            lMatch.Add(index);
            index++;
        }
    }
    return lPattern.SequenceEqual(lMatch);
}
```

Comment: -1 for the Hungarian notation and lack of reasoning about how that approach is different and why it might be preferred.

Comment: @RobH Sorry the difference and why it might be preferred is not apparent to you.

Comment: I can see the difference but am wondering *why* I would prefer this over the OP's solution? You allocate more memory and process the entire pattern and string to match even if it is incorrect early on. I see this as a **worse** solution in at least 2 ways - not to mention readability.

Comment: @RobH Then see what you see.   There is no O(n) lookup.   Checking for a difference early is an expense and dictionary doe not offer an ordinal index.   Did you test against your solution for speed.

Comment: I was thinking of my own code which used a `HashSet` for checking for the values instead of the O(n) lookup. Sorry about that. Yes, my solution is faster.

Comment: @RobH Then why not post your solution?

Comment: Because I have *reviewed* the code in the question and Janos has already mentioned using an additional Set to reduce the complexity of the lookup with a great description of the issue. You've simply dumped code on a page with absolutely no reasoning given - much the same as most of your posts.

Comment: Janos says "To make the lookup by value faster, you can add a set for values." **with an explanation**. The site is about learning but you seem to be allergic to providing explanations for what you say.

Comment: @RobH My answer *reviews* existing code.  "Use a HashSet to store current values".   I cannot test speed without your solution so I guess I will just  need to take you word.